# TeamCity behind an Apache proxy server

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy, teamcity

I have installed latest TeamCity 9, now I want to access it from the public Internet via HTTPS. So I followed the instructions to setup TeamCity behind an Apache proxy server, as [described in the official docs](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/How+To...#HowTo...-SetUpTeamCitybehindaProxyingServer).

Now when I try to access the TeamCity server in the browser I get a 404 page from the Tomcat server. I am not sure what I did wrong, but the issue might be related to the `/tc` sub folder I have moved the content ROOT into (as described in the docs).

When I connect directly from the server to `http://localhost:8111/tc` I get exactly the same 404 message.

I feel a bit lost here.
Any ideas where I should look for the error?

PS: When I move the content ROOT back into the original folder, and set the Apache proxy accordingly, then it works fine. So the issue is indeed related to the `/tc` sub folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me

Step 1: I installed teamcity at the port `8080`

Step 2: Moved all contents of `<teamcity_home>\webapps\ROOT\*.*` to `<teamcity_home>\webapps\teamcity`

Step 3: Created `<Apache_Home>\conf\extra\httpd-teamcity.conf` with the following contents
`ProxyRequests       Off
ProxyPass           /teamcity http://localhost:8080/teamcity connectiontimeout=240 timeout=1200
ProxyPassReverse    /teamcity http://localhost:8080/teamcity`

Step 4: Added the following to `<Apache_Home>\conf\httpd.conf` file

`#Include TeamCity Settings
Include conf/extra/httpd-teamcity.conf`

and uncommented the following

`# Modules to load to redirect teamcity
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so`

Step 5: Accessed Teamcity via `http://localhost:8080/teamcity`OR`http://localhost/teamcity`

Note: you can no longer access teamcity via `http://localhost:8080`
And update the configuration of your agent to point to the new server location.